# Oracle Forms/Applications in Internet Explorer 8 using JInitator

Tags: java, oracle, internet-explorer, web-applications, oracleforms

Has anyone been able to get Oracle Forms running JInitator to loan in Internet Explorer 8 yet?  I have tried removing all add-ons, various version of Java, add the domain to the trusted sites using wildcards, and using compatibility mode to no avail.  I am looking to get our Oracle guys to kick there Internet Explorer 6 habit.  This is related to Oracle E-Business.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to replace the file C:\Program Files\Oracle\JInitiator x.x.x.xx\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll with the sun version of the file.

On my system the sun version is here C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll

Comment: I am going to award this answer to Simon here but I will note that Oracle as issued a statement that this is not a supported solution and is use at your own risk.  Oracle Support for JInitiator 1.3 will end on July 31, 2009. They are pushing a new native Sun JRE plug-in that works with standard versions of Java.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the jvm.dll did not work for me. The proper way to switch to Sun's Java VM which worked for me is by changing this

```
baseHTMLjinitiator=basejini.htm
```

to
this

```
baseHTMLjinitiator=basejpi.htm
```

in the formsweb.cfg file. IE8 on XP SP3, DEP enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as of now IE8 is not certified for Oracle Apps. You may hear a good news soon!

Comment: Well, workaround mentioned my Simon may work, but Oracle has still not certified it. So, it's risky to use IE8 for Oracle Apps.

FYI, IE8 will be certified by Oracle Forms 10g Release 2 (10.1.2.4) and Oracle Forms 11g Release 1 (yet to be released).

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed Oracle Forms 10g on Windows7 and get both JPI and Jinitiator working.

Steps

- Install Dev10g
- Apply Patch p5983622_10123_WINNT
- Manually install JRE 1.6 upd 20
- Configure formsweb.cfg for JPI
- This is preferred method as you don't have to do following steps on each client

If you want to run using Jinitiator

- Configure formsweb.cfg for Jinitiator
- Once Jinitiator is installed on client machine [replace jvm.dll](http://sathyabh.at/2009/06/27/fixing-internet-explorer-crash-on-launching-oracle-forms-application-with-jinitiator/)

Answer (score 0):

As Mundit has said, it is still not certified.

Do you have access to Metalink? Note: 760326.1 When Will IE 8 Be Certified With E-Bussines Suite? gives some further information.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine told me to do the following:

Add server to Trusted Sites and then:

1. Tools / Internet options
2. Security tab -> Trusted Sites
3. Click on Custom level... button
4. scroll to the end and find "Enable XSS filter" option (3rd from the bottom)
5. set it to Disable

This works for me with 11i and R12 apps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add to Simon's solution. I did the trick on one computer but couldn't repeat it on a second one. Finally, I discovered that replacing the file does not work when using the file jvm.dll from java 6 update 14. It worked fine when I used the jvm.dll file from version 13.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something even more intersting about JINIT.  It was de-supported by Oracle as of July 31st.  You might want to consider moving to the SUN JPI instad.  This is the recommended route by Oracle now, and since JINIT will not be getting updates it's the safest.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are great!  I was pulling my hair off their roots and now got it fixed.

1. I went to Control Panel/System/Advanced tab/Startup and Recovery panel hit Settings.  Then in the System Startup panel hit Edit. There made noexecute=AlwaysOff and saved.
2. As per Simon I swapped the Oracle jvm.dll with the Java version.  I had to downgrade that to jvm.dll version 10.0.0.23 though.
3. Also as per Simon I went to Tools/Internet Options/Security/Trusted Sites/Custom Level and disabled Enable XSS Filter.

Not sure whether #1 applies to everyone but it was necessary for me.  Good Luck!
Fouwaaz

Answer (score -1):

1. Install the latest JRE from Sun. I have installed "jre-6u10-windows-i586-p-s.exe".
2. Copy the jvm.dll (appx Ver 11.0.0.15 size 2.25 MB (2,359,296 bytes)) from the “C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client” folder and paste it to folder where the Jinitiator is installed (default location) e.g “C:\Program Files\Oracle\JInitiator 1.3.1.22\bin\hotspot”.
3. It will work fine with the IE8 browser.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

We're having a similiar problem.

I believe Oracle is aware of this, and is working on a patch, which is not ready yet.

Comment: Yeah it's different then the normal JInitiator plugin based issues where IE crashes.  In our case the app starts to load java and never spawns the forms.

Comment: We are having the same issue in some e-Business installations with IE7