# Oracle Forms 11g Not work with IE8

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am lunched Oracle Forms 11. Everything is fine except one thing. Internet explorer can not start them. Everything works with IE9, IE10, Chrome, Firefox. The problem is with IE8. We tried changing security settings, re-installing  Oracle Forms 11g, but with no result. There is no errors or warnings from java side. In fact it looks like Java does not start at all. Problem is with different OS (Windows 7 x64 or x32, windows XP x86). We tied different Java versions (1.6.0_41, 1.6.0_43, 1.70_21) but nothing. Maybe someone can suggest a solution how solve this phenomena.

Comment: A related question not exactly same was asked before might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893767/oracle-forms-applications-in-internet-explorer-8-using-jinitator

Comment: java console must be showing some error. Can you paste it?

Comment: We don't use JInitator. That was the problem, that java console didn't show any error, and log was with no useful information either. But we found the problem, there was wrong path of JavaScript in webutiljpi.htm. We copied some of configuration from Oracle Forms 10g and it turns out that JavaScript path is different from Oracle Forms 11g.

Answer (score 0):

We Found the problem. After forms design migration some of configuration was copied from Oracle Forms 10g. It turns out that JavaScript sorce in webutiljpi.htm is different from Oracle Forms 11g. But the strangest thing that Forms didn't work only with IE8.